# Can node.js code result in race conditions?

Tags: node.js, race-condition

From what I read, race conditions occur when different threads try to change a shared variable, which can result in a value that's not possible with any serial order of execution of those threads.

But code in node.js runs in a single thread, so, does that mean code written in node.js is free of race conditions?

Comment: You could have some problem if you declare your variables inside functions as implict global var instead of local var of the closure. In these two answers (one i answerd and one i was answered), you can find some examples about the problem you are wishing not to meet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229739/race-condition-and-common-mistakes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002349/use-parameter-in-callbacks-from-function-which-called-it/

Answer (score 35):

**Yes**, race conditions (in the sense of a shared resource having an inconsistent value due to order of events) can still happen anywhere that there's a point of suspension that could lead to other code being run (with threads its at *any line*), take for example this piece of async code that is entirely single threaded:

```js
var accountBalance = 0;

async function getAccountBalance() {
    // Suppose this was asynchronously from a database or something
    return accountBalance;
};

async function setAccountBalance(value) {
    // Suppose this was asynchronously from a database or something
    accountBalance = value;
};

async function increment(value, incr) {
    return value + incr;
};

async function add$50() {
    var balance, newBalance;
    balance = await getAccountBalance();
    newBalance = await increment(balance, 50);
    await setAccountBalance(newBalance);
};

async function main() {
    var transaction1, transaction2;
    transaction1 = add$50();
    transaction2 = add$50();
    await transaction1;
    await transaction2;
    console.log('$' + await getAccountBalance());
    // Can print either $50 or $100
    // which it prints is dependent on what order
    // things arrived on the message queue, for this very simple
    // dummy implementation it actually prints $50 because
    // all values are added to the message queue immediately
    // so it actually alternates between the two async functions
};

main();
```

This code has suspension points at every single await and as such could context switch between the two functions at a bad time producing "$50" rather than the expected "$100", this is essentially the same example as Wikipedia's example for Race Conditions in threads but with explicit points of suspension/re-entry.

Just like threads though you can solve such race conditions with things like a Lock (aka mutex). So we could prevent the above race condition in the same way as threads:

```
var accountBalance = 0;

class Lock {
    constructor() {
        this._locked = false;
        this._waiting = [];
    }

    lock() {
        var unlock = () => {
            var nextResolve;
            if (this._waiting.length > 0) {
                nextResolve = this._waiting.pop(0);
                nextResolve(unlock);
            } else {
                this._locked = false;
            }
        };
        if (this._locked) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                this._waiting.push(resolve);
            });
        } else {
            this._locked = true;
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                resolve(unlock);
            });
        }
    }
}

var account = new Lock();

 async function getAccountBalance() {
    // Suppose this was asynchronously from a database or something
    return accountBalance;
};

async function setAccountBalance(value) {
    // Suppose this was asynchronously from a database or something
    accountBalance = value;
};

async function increment(value, incr) {
    return value + incr;
};

async function add$50() {
    var unlock, balance, newBalance;

    unlock = await account.lock();

    balance = await getAccountBalance();
    newBalance = await increment(balance, 50);
    await setAccountBalance(newBalance);

    await unlock();
};

async function main() {
    var transaction1, transaction2;
    transaction1 = add$50();
    transaction2 = add$50();
    await transaction1;
    await transaction2;
    console.log('$' + await getAccountBalance()); // Now will always be $100 regardless
};

main();
```

Comment: For the first code, you are introducing the race condition intentionally.
transaction1 = add$50();
    transaction2 = add$50();
    await transaction1;
    await transaction2;
is like Promise.all(transaction1, transaction2)

You should do this to avoid it:
 await add$50();
  await add$50();

Comment: The point is to demonstrate that if things happen concurrently then yes you can still result in similar race conditions as with threads. So yes I have introduced a race condition intentionally to demonstrate the point. You might say have an API in which you do something transactional as a different example but I didn't want the example to be even more complex.

Comment: Isn't there still a race condition in this code? The state could change in between when you check `if (this._locked)` and the action you take, so you think it's safe to get a lock but the other thread grabbed the lock rather after you determined there was not one.. Two threads could be trying to get locks at almost the exact same time. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something. I'm new to concurrency and that's why I found this article.

Comment: No, this code isn't multithreaded at all, in fact it runs entirely in a single thread.

Concurrency and threading are actually different concepts, effectively concurrency is the ability for multiple tasks to interleave their work. Threading/paralellism though is where things run actually at the same time.

My example purely concerns concurrency and does not suffer threading problems because interleaving points are explicit (wherever there is an "await").

While some environments do add real threads to Javascript, most expose it via concurrency so thread-style race conditions can't occur

Comment: As a particular example, threads in web browsers running Javascript are exposed using `Worker` objects. There are only two ways to communicate with `Worker`, either the `SharedArrayBuffer` object or `MessageChannel`s. When using `SharedArrayBuffer` real race conditions can absolutely occur, however their scope is limited to those objects and can't interrupt arbitrary code. When using `MessageChannel` responses to work are queued to be fired as events, these events only fire when no JS is currently running, so no thread-based race conditions can occur when using `MessageChannel`.

Answer (score 28):

Yes. Node.js can run into race conditions as soon as you start sharing resources.

I mistakenly also thought you couldn't get race conditions in Node.js because it's single threaded nature, but as soon as you use a shared resource outside of node (e.g. a file from the file system) you can get into a race condition. I posted an example of this issue in this question when I was trying to understand this: [node.js readfile woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368806/node-js-readfile-woes)

What is different in Node.js from other environments is that you have a single thread of JavaScript execution so there is only one JavaScript instance running your code (as oppossed to a threaded environment in which there are many threads executing your app code at the same time.)

Answer (score 24):

No. That's true you cannot have race condition on a single threaded, **non I/O doing** program.

But node.js is mainly fast because of its non blocking way of programming. Non blocking means that setting a listener to a response event, you can do something else while waiting this response.

Why ? *Because the work for getting the response is done on another thread.* Database, filesystem, run on other thread, client obviously runs on another computer and you program workflow can depend on
its response.

**So strictly speaking, node.js runs on one thread, but your program workflow, wich include I/O (database, filesystem), client and everything, runs on many thread.**

So there still can be race condition if you do a request to add something to a database, and then just send a request to delete it without waiting for the response of the first request. *There would be no race condition if the database was running in the same thread as node.js, and the request was just a function call executed immediatly.*

Comment: A race condition has nothing to do with threads. Threads result in race conditions because they interleave the execution of the code. Async calls also do the same, so race conditions are possible.

Comment: Async calls without unpredictable I/O cannot result in race conditions. If single-threaded async code results in race conditions, it is always because external ressources are involved.

Comment: @AbiusX Would be nice if you can give a code example of this!

Comment: @jillro Same for you, would be nice with a code example!

Answer (score 10):

Race conditions can still happen as they really have nothing to do with threads, but on making assumptions about event timing and sequence, so threads are just an example of that.

Node.js is single-threaded, but still concurrent, and race conditions are possible. For example:

```
var http = require('http');

var size;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  size = 0;

  req.on('data', function (data) {
    size += data.length;
  });

  req.on('end', function () {
    res.end(size.toString());
  })

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

This program is supposed to send clients a size of their request. If you test it, will seem to work correct. But it is actually based on implicit assumption, that nothing happens between request start and end events. If there are 2 or more concurrent clients it will not work.

This happens here because `size` variable is shared, a lot like when two threads share a variable. You can think about an abstract "asynchrnous context", which is a lot like thread, but it can only be suspended at certain points.

Comment: okay! However, in this case, if the `size` variable is inside the `createServer` callback, then each user gets a separate copy of `size`, right?

Comment: I do not agree. They have to do with threads and I/O which is conceptually equivalent to sharing the workflow of the programm on many threads. You cannot have race conditions on a single-thread , non I/O  doing program (I mean a program just accpeting parameter and returning exit value).

Comment: Here there is another thread acting on the workflow wich are clients. If you put all your programm in a main loop checking for new request queue, and then nest a loop checking for new data in the request, there will be no race condition anymore. That is because another thread can call (through event) a small step of the request processing workflow that whenever it wants that there is concurrency and race condition.

Comment: What you describe is not a race condition. You are describing shared state and the misunderstanding of it in Node.js.

Comment: In a certain way we could say there is a race condition *between clients* because of the shared state in the server, but there is indeed no race condition in the server itself.

Answer (score 9):

No. Node.js is free of race conditions that would be caused by context switching; however, you can still write a node.js program where asynchronous events happening in an unexpected order result in an inconsistent state.

For example, suppose you have two functions. The first sends a message through a WebSocket and, in a callback, saves the reply. The second function deletes all saved replies. Calling the functions in order does not guarantee an empty message list. It is important to consider all possible event orderings when doing asynchronous programming.

EDIT: Here's some example code

```
var messages = [];

...

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('ask', { question: 'How many fish do you have?' });
    socket.on('reply', function (data) {
        messages.push(data);
    });
    ...
    wipe();
});

function wipe() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        messages = [];
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: The race condition is indeed between client and node.js program. Note that given the client behaviour, output of node.js program is known.

Comment: @Guilro That's a good point. I interpreted the question to mean "Can a Node.js program exhibit race conditions?" The answer is yes. If the intended question was "Can a pure JS application with no I/O have race conditions?" the answer is no. I think the former is a more useful question because most Node.js applications will have I/O.

Comment: @Guilro Wait a minute. Since sockets use the Internet, knowing client behavior isn't sufficient. You would also have to know network and OS behavior.

Comment: Yep, of course :) anyway you are right about what was the intended question, and that is why I voted your answer. It was just to give precisions.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes. It can.

Race condition in Nodejs is feasible when you use `cluster` module to initialise multiple workers.

## The case

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var fs = require('fs');
if(cluster.isMaster){
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
        cluster.fork();
    }
}else{
    fs.watch('/path/to/file',function(){
        var anotherFile = '/path/to/anotherFile';
        fs.readFile(anotherFile,function(er,data){
             if(er){
                 throw er;
             }
             data = +data+1;
             fs.writeFile(anotherFile,data,function(er){
                 if(er){
                     throw er;
                 }
                 fs.readFile(anotherFile,function(er,newData){
                     if(er){
                         throw er;
                     }
                     console.log(newData); //newData is now undetermined
                 });
             });
        });
    });
}
```

Whenever you change the watched file, 4 workers will execute the handler at the same time. This behaviour causes the undetermined `newData`.

## The solution

```
if(cluster.isMaster){
    var lock = {};
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(Object.keys(cluster.workers).length >= 4){
            return clearInterval(timer);
        }
        //note that this lock won't 100% work if workers are forked at the same time with loop.
        cluster.fork().on('message',function(id){
             var isLocked = lock[id];
             if(isLocked){
                 return console.log('This task has already been handled');
             }
             lock[id] = 1;
             this.send('No one has done it yet');
        });
    },100);
}else{
     process.on('message',function(){
        //only one worker can execute this task
        fs.watch('/path/to/file',function(){
            var anotherFile = '/path/to/anotherFile';
            fs.readFile(anotherFile,function(er,data){
                 if(er){
                     throw er;
                 }
                 data = +data+1;
                 fs.writeFile(anotherFile,data,function(er){
                     if(er){
                        throw er;
                     }
                     fs.readFile(anotherFile,function(er,newData){
                         if(er){
                             throw er;
                         }
                         console.log(newData); //newData is now determined
                     });
                 });
            });
        });
     });
     //ask the master for permission
     process.send('watch');
}
```