# Use parameter in callbacks from function which called it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, scope, parameter-passing

if i call a function A passing a parameter param, in which an asynchronous function B is called, will the callback C of the asynchronous function B be able to use the parameter param given to function A ? if yes, will this change if in the time between the function B start and the callback C is invoked i re-invoke function A?

Example:

```
function A(param) {

  value1 = param;
  doc = "hello";
  //this is the async function B;
  database.insert(doc, function() {
    //this is the invoked callback C when the async function is solved. 

    console.log(value1)

    //can i log value1? yes. if yes, will this change if i re-invoke 
    //function A before the callback is invoked or two different processes will start?

  })


}


A('hello');
A('not hello');
```

Wondering if this, if for the second time A function is invoked before the callback function  of the previous invocation, will print the right values on console:

hello; 
not hello;

and never 
not hello;
not hello;

cause second time's invocation infects first time one.

Comment: **Declare your local variables with `var`.**

Comment: thank you first. is this needed for the correct working or just advised ? @Pointy

Comment: It's just a very important habit to get into, and an important concept to understand.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for the advice. But it's not what i was asking about! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the inline callback passed to `database.insert()` will be able to see the argument passed to function `A()`.  A function has access to any arguments or even local variables in the containing functions.

And, each one will be saved separately so you can call `A()` as many times as you want and they will each retain separate arguments.

This concept is called a closure, a separate closure is created for each invocation of `A()` and the closure stays alive as long as any code inside it (including asynchronous callbacks) has not yet completed.

You WILL though need to declare your local variables with `var` in front of them for them to be truly local variables and unique for each invocation of `A()`.  Without the `var`, they become implicit global variables and one invocation of `A()` will mess with the global variables of another invocation of `A()`.  If you do it like this, you are safe:

```
function A(param) {

  var value1 = param;
  var doc = "hello";
  //this is the async function B;
  database.insert(doc, function() {
    //this is the invoked callback C when the async function is solved. 

    console.log(value1);
    console.log(param);
    console.log(doc);

    //can i log value1? yes. if yes, will this change if i re-invoke 
    //function A before the callback is invoked or two different processes will start?

  })


}


A('hello');
A('not hello');
```

Comment: ok thank u. but will this value change if i reinvoke the function after a first invocation before the first invocation callback is solved? i mean, the first invocation callbak will print the first passed parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the variable `value1` to be captured in the callback closure, you need to declare it as a local variable:

```
var value1 = param;
```

Comment: Function arguments are part of the closure too.  There is no need to assign it to a local variable.

Comment: That's true, but he's not using the argument in his callback, he's using `value1`. So I showed how to capture that. In this example program they're interchangeable, but in the real application they might not be (e.g. `var value1 = param * something`).